# how to make android youtube player keep playing even though there is overlay on top of player

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

When I draw out the drawer, the player will be paused and there will be a message in the logcat:youtube video playback stopped due to unauthorized overlay on top of player....

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution. Put the video in a popup window. I suppose you are using Android. On the playstore there are many apps doing this. Using the standard youtube api 1.0 in a window. It usually stays on top and keeps playing no mather what. Most of these Apps use the stand out lib, which you can find here. https://github.com/pingpongboss/StandOut
Good luck!

Comment: hello. do you have more example? i have some problem about it